# A question about the unbounded derived category of the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

In this moment I am trying to understand the derived category of the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables over a field $k$, $R=k[x_{1},x_{2},\dots]$ and I am wonder if it is true that $Hom_{D(R)}(E(k),k)=0$ where $E(k)$ denotes the injective envelope of the fiel $k$  in tha category of modules over the ring $R$. Can somebody tell me if that is true?

Comment: Since $Hom_{D(R)}(E(k),k)=Hom_R(E(k),k)$, this isn't really a question about the derived category.

Comment: I agree with you, Dag Oskar Madsen. In any case, is it true that $Hom_{R}(E(k),k)=0$? and more general, Is it true that $Ext_{R}^{i}(E(k),k)=0$ for all $i\geq 0$?.